# Azure ML error: NotImplementedError: Linux distribution debian 11. does not have automatic support

Tags: python, azure, .net-core, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to train my model as an Azure ML job.
I train my model as a Docker container. However I keep getting this error when executing the Azure ML job:

```
Warning: Falling back to use azure cli login credentials.
If you run your code in unattended mode, i.e., where you can't give a user input, then we recommend to use ServicePrincipalAuthentication or MsiAuthentication.
Please refer to aka.ms/aml-notebook-auth for different authentication mechanisms in azureml-sdk.
2022-10-24 13:01:49.839951 | ActivityCompleted: Activity=_dataflow, HowEnded=Failure, Duration=903.73 [ms], Info = {'activity_id': '9a734e5b-752b-4f5d-bcc3-682eee0346eb', 'activity_name': '_dataflow', 'activity_type': 'InternalCall', 'app_name': 'dataset', 'source': 'azureml.dataset', 'version': '1.46.0', 'dataprepVersion': '4.5.7', 'sparkVersion': '', 'subscription': '308339c6-d455-4395-ae62-5de2a35792e6', 'run_id': 'experiment-niels-i4t_1666616328_bd67e032', 'resource_group': 'i4talent_mlops', 'workspace_name': 'mlops_template', 'experiment_id': '0e131a58-b02e-471f-bf9f-e8c12dfc045f', 'location': 'germanywestcentral', 'completionStatus': 'Success', 'durationMs': 364.36}, Exception=NotImplementedError; Linux distribution debian 11. does not have automatic support. 
Missing packages: {'liblttng-ust.so.0', 'libcurl.so.4'}
.NET Core 3.1 can still be used via `dotnetcore2` if the required dependencies are installed.
Visit https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-linux for Linux distro specific .NET Core install instructions.
Follow your distro specific instructions to install `dotnet-runtime-*` and replace `*` with `3.1.23`.

2022-10-24 13:01:49.839875 | ActivityCompleted: Activity=to_pandas_dataframe, HowEnded=Failure, Duration=904.0 [ms], Info = {'activity_id': '043091e8-2c47-4a1d-be34-72200a827822', 'activity_name': 'to_pandas_dataframe', 'activity_type': 'PublicApi', 'app_name': 'TabularDataset', 'source': 'azureml.dataset', 'version': '1.46.0', 'dataprepVersion': '4.5.7', 'sparkVersion': '', 'subscription': '308339c6-d455-4395-ae62-5de2a35792e6', 'run_id': 'experiment-niels-i4t_1666616328_bd67e032', 'resource_group': 'i4talent_mlops', 'workspace_name': 'mlops_template', 'experiment_id': '0e131a58-b02e-471f-bf9f-e8c12dfc045f', 'location': 'germanywestcentral', 'completionStatus': 'Success', 'durationMs': 364.36}, Exception=NotImplementedError; Linux distribution debian 11. does not have automatic support. 
Missing packages: {'liblttng-ust.so.0', 'libcurl.so.4'}
.NET Core 3.1 can still be used via `dotnetcore2` if the required dependencies are installed.
Visit https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-linux for Linux distro specific .NET Core install instructions.
Follow your distro specific instructions to install `dotnet-runtime-*` and replace `*` with `3.1.23`.

Cleaning up all outstanding Run operations, waiting 300.0 seconds
1 items cleaning up...
Cleanup took 0.08137202262878418 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotnetcore2/runtime.py", line 271, in attempt_get_deps
    blob_deps_to_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotnetcore2/runtime.py", line 263, in blob_deps_to_file
    blob = request.urlopen(deps_url, context=ssl_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 5, in <module>
    train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlops_i4t/machine_learning/model_utils.py", line 56, in train
    df = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/data/_loggerfactory.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/data/tabular_dataset.py", line 168, in to_pandas_dataframe
    dataflow = get_dataflow_for_execution(self._dataflow, 'to_pandas_dataframe', 'TabularDataset')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/data/_loggerfactory.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/data/abstract_dataset.py", line 221, in _dataflow
    dataprep().api._datastore_helper._set_auth_type(self._registration.workspace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/dataprep/api/_datastore_helper.py", line 177, in _set_auth_type
    get_engine_api().set_aml_auth(SetAmlAuthMessageArgument(auth_type, json.dumps(auth_value)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/dataprep/api/engineapi/api.py", line 19, in get_engine_api
    _engine_api = EngineAPI()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/dataprep/api/engineapi/api.py", line 102, in __init__
    self._message_channel = launch_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/dataprep/api/engineapi/engine.py", line 333, in launch_engine
    dependencies_path = runtime.ensure_dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotnetcore2/runtime.py", line 285, in ensure_dependencies
    if not attempt_get_deps(missing_pkgs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotnetcore2/runtime.py", line 279, in attempt_get_deps
    raise NotImplementedError(err_msg + '\n' + _unsupported_help_msg)
NotImplementedError: Linux distribution debian 11. does not have automatic support. 
Missing packages: {'liblttng-ust.so.0', 'libcurl.so.4'}
.NET Core 3.1 can still be used via `dotnetcore2` if the required dependencies are installed.
Visit https://aka.ms/dotnet-install-linux for Linux distro specific .NET Core install instructions.
Follow your distro specific instructions to install `dotnet-runtime-*` and replace `*` with `3.1.23`.
```

My cluster where I run this job on is a STANDARD_DS3_V2.

Furthermore, my Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN pip install azure-cli
RUN az login --service-principal -u "xxxxxxxx"  -p "xxxxxx" --tenant "xxxxxx"
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install . --use-feature=fast-deps
RUN echo "Finished installing packages."
```

I am lost tbh... Did anyone experience the same?
How can I change the dot net core version in my Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian is not supportive of all the .net versions. Debian 11 will function with .Net core 3.1, and .Net 6.

The following versions of .NET are no longer supported:

•   .NET 5

•   .NET Core 3.0

•   .NET Core 2.2

•   .NET Core 2.1

•   .NET Core 2.0

Before installing .Net, run the commands which are mentioned below to add the Microsoft package signing key to your list of trusted keys.

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Install the .Net SDK allows you to install .Net 6.0.

```
sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

using the following commands we can work with the Debian 11 connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

What I also needed was `apt install -y liblttng-ust0` with debian 11 and python 3.10.0. Just the solution posted here was not enough.